# Using Zabbix Template ETCD by HTTP Template for etcd with https enabled

Tags: zabbix

I have tried to use official ETCD Template in Zabbix, there is one available by name of ETCD by HTTP, however on my etcd I have https enabled, therefore I have to pass SSL certificates that are located on my machine for etcdctl. However I do not see any ability to pass in endpoint the location of ssl or something in order for template to sucesfully connect to my ETCD cluster, any help or advices are appreciated.

The error that I get in Zabbix is

```
Cannot perform request: OpenSSL/3.0.9: error:0A000412:SSL routines::sslv3 alert bad certificate
```

As I noticed that error appears due to not passing ca-certificates when trying to connect to etcd.

The only value that is included in documentation for that tempalate is {$ETCD.SCHEME} and I have set it to https, but is still required certificates somehow passed